# having trouble grabbing html input value using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html file and I want to grab the text that is entered in the input field using javascript. I have tried a few different ways but nothing seems to be working properly. Here is the code that I have right now.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="searchingterm">
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="search">
    </form>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var searched = document.getElementById("search").value;
            console.log(searched)
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

i also tried using jquery but that didnt do anything either.

Comment: The `input` doesn't have a `value`, and you haven't attached this to any sort of handler (click, change). What are your intentions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

basically, the problem is that you are not assigning anything to that input and also you dont have a function to trigger the `search`.

your code was right, you just needed to change it a little bit.

```js
function search() {
  var searched = document.getElementById("search").value;
  console.log(searched)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="search">
  </form>
  <button onclick="search()"> search</button>
</body>

</html>
```

here having the script on the `body`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="search">
  </form>
  <button onclick="search()"> search</button>
  <script>
    function search() {
      var searched = document.getElementById("search").value;
      console.log(searched)
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: where should I put the function. If i put it in a script tag above the html and when i run it i get this: `(index):25 Uncaught TypeError: search is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):25)`

Comment: @OmarJandali I added another snippet with the function inside the `script` tag